# Is the expression 'im Amt' correct?

Tags: preposition, article

I came across a sentence on this [website](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/kommunikation-auf-dem-amt/l-40330734/rs-39360114):

> Wenn du in Deutschland etwas auf einem Amt erledigen musst, zum
> Beispiel bei der Agentur für Arbeit oder im Einwohnermeldeamt, ist
> höfliche Kommunikation gefragt.

I was wonder if 'auf einem Amt' is the only correct expression. Can we say 'in einem Amt', since in English we say 'in an office'?

Comment: Genau genommen ist die Agentur für Arbeit kein Amt, sondern eine Anstalt des öffentlichen Rechts. Das wissen aber viele nicht.

Comment: @userunknown ach so! Was ist der Unterschied zwischen ein Amt und eine Anstalt?

Comment: Sicher gibt es massig Unterschiede, die sich aus dem Verwaltungsrecht ergeben. Der einzige, der offensichtlich ist, ist der, dass die Beschäftigten keine Beamten sind.

Comment: @userunknown Korrekte Bemerkung, aber im Kontext der Frage nicht zielführend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either "in" or "auf" or "bei".

"Auf dem Amt" meaning "at the office" is a quite special use of "auf", the preposition is only used in that sense with administrative offices.

> Sie hat einen Termin auf dem (*or:* beim *or:* im) Ordnungsamt.
> Ich muss heute aufs (*or:* zum *or:* ins) Rathaus wegen meines Reisepasses.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is 'ich muss heute im Rathaus wegn meines Reisepasses' / 'ich muss heute bei dem Rathaus wegn meines Reisepasses' falsch?

Comment: @Dennis you need a preposition of direction, not one of place, with this use of "müssen". "Ich muss heute **ins** Rathaus wegen meines Reisepasses" is correct, too.

Comment: Thanks. This is one thing that currently really confuses me. So we can either say 'Ich muss heute ins Rathaus' or 'ich muss heute in dem Rathaus *sein*' ? When we are referring to a position we must use the combination 'muss'+'sein' whereas when we are referring to the direction we don't need to add 'sein'?

Comment: @Dennis That's just vocabulary, you can use "müssen" with a prepositional of direction to mean 'to have to go somewhere' in German. It's a shortened use that the English language doesn't have.

Comment: The same use also exists for *wollen* btw.  *Wir wollen heute Abend ins Kino.* *Ich will gerne mal nach Japan.*